# Android ADB stop application command like "force-stop" for non rooted device

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to stop application on Android 2.3.7 device. But in this version of Android I can't use "force-stop" command. Do you know any other ways to close application on non rooted device?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

**The first way**
*Requires root*


Use `kill`:

`adb shell ps` => Will list all running processes on the device and their process ids
`adb shell kill <PID>` => Instead of `<PID>` use process id of your application

**The second way**
In Eclipse open `DDMS` perspective.
In `Devices` view you will find all running processes.
Choose the process and click on `Stop`.

[image]

**The third way**
*It will kill only background process of an application.*

`adb shell am kill [options] <PACKAGE>` => Kill all processes associated with  (the app's package name). This command kills only processes that are safe to kill and that will not impact the user experience.
Options are:

--user <USER_ID> | all | current: Specify user whose processes to kill; all users if not specified.

**The fourth way**
*Requires root*


`adb shell pm disable <PACKAGE>` => Disable the given package or component (written as "package/class").

**The fifth way**
*Note that run-as is only supported for apps that are signed with debug keys.*


`run-as <package-name> kill <pid>`

**The sixth way**
*Introduced in Honeycomb*
`adb shell am force-stop <PACKAGE>` => Force stop everything associated with  (the app's package name).

P.S.: I know that the sixth method didn't work for you, but I think that it's important to add this method to the list, so everyone will know it.

Comment: Thanks for answer but when I use `kill` I get "Operation not permitted" error. My device is non rooted and I have to do this via ADB.

Comment: I used the sixth one.  Works like a charm.  I used it to stop the main app then do a factory reset and reinstall.  This little script might be useful (semi-colons indicate line breaks, replace them):  adb shell am force-stop <PACKAGE>;   adb shell wipe data;   adb shell wipe cache;   adb reboot recovery;   TIMEOUT 80 /nobreak;   adb install <APK_NAME.apk>;

Comment: what kind of way is equivalent to the user going to the app details and choose "force stop" ? is the 6th one? also, how do you make an app become in "stopped" state , which mean it doesn't get any intent, any event whatsoever, till the user opens the app?

Comment: Thanks for including #6, nowadays most people will be targeting above honeycomb. This worked exactly right for the scripts I'm writing:

adb shell am force-stop <PACKAGE>

Comment: How can I do this programmatically from my application? Any example code would be more helpful..

Comment: FYI about run-as command, the complete structure is """adb exec-out run-as com.abc(pkg name) kill 31736(pid)"""

Comment: operation not permitted... what is that means...? do i need root?

Comment: @gumuruh I got this "operation not permitted". This seems to require a rooted device. However the sixth option, `adb shell am force-stop <PACKAGE> ` worked.

Comment: These don't work for a protected package

Answer (score 7):

If you have a rooted device you can use `kill` command

Connect to your device with adb:

```
adb shell
```

Once the session is established, you have to escalade privileges:

```
su
```

Then

```
ps
```

will list running processes. Note down the PID of the process you want to terminate. Then get rid of it

```
kill PID
```

Comment: if the process keeps running even after got killed. What should i do then? @EricVB

Answer (score 6):

If you want to kill the Sticky Service,the following command **NOT WORKING**:

```
adb shell am force-stop <PACKAGE>
adb shell kill <PID>
```

The following command is **WORKING**:

```
adb shell pm disable <PACKAGE>
```

If you want to restart the app,you must run command below first:

```
adb shell pm enable <PACKAGE>
```

Comment: but is that require us to be in root mode?

Comment: Just like you, the `am force-stop <PACKAGE>` command was not working for me... So I ended up using the `pm disable <PACKAGE>` , and `pm enable <PACKAGE>` combination ... However , since I also needed to launch the app, I added an extra command line 
`monkey -p <PACKAGE> -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1`

Answer (score 1):

To kill from the application, you can do:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```