# Android terminate app from terminal

Tags: android, testing, android-studio, terminal, ide

I usually have to test certain crashes with the terminate app button in Android studio. But now I need other testers to do the same without IDE, is there a way to terminate an app from terminal? Some ADB command?

Comment: What do you mean by terminate? Do you mean 'Force Stop' ? You can do this in the Device itself.

Comment: This is a duplicate question, check this:
[Android ADB stop application command like “force-stop” for non rooted device](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17829606/3099776)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

`adb shell pm clear com.my.app.package`

which will stop the app process and clear out all the stored data for that app.
Also, you can close forcefully by using `pid`,

```
adb shell kill <PID>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kill is probably your friend here

You can list all running processes on the device and their process ids

```
adb shell ps
```

Instead of  use process id of your application

```
adb shell kill <PID>
```

Answer (score 1):

`adb killall` and `adb shell kill PID` will work if you have privilege But

> [am(Activity Manager)](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html)

is an awesome command to play with adb. Have you tried?

```
am force-stop "your.package.name"
```