# Need a way to remove the app from recent applist

Tags: testcomplete

I have scenario where I need to remove the tested App from recent App list in Android.

Issue is I am not able to click on recent App button using TC.

Is there any way where we can acomplish this using TC script.

Thanks

Suvidh

Comment: Try using the solution from the [Android ADB stop application command like “force-stop” for non rooted device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829606/android-adb-stop-application-command-like-force-stop-for-non-rooted-device) link. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using this code:

```
var dvcName = "...";
var pckgName = "...";
Mobile.Device(dvcName).ShellExecute("adb shell pm uninstall " + pckgName);
```

Comment: I don't want to Uninstall the app. I only want it to remove from recent app.