# Why adb shell am kill <PACKAGE_NAME> doesn't kill process?

Tags: android

I want to kill app process of my app for testing purpose. I want to test activity restoration.
I send my app to background by pressing home button. Then I run this command `adb shell am kill <PACKAGE_NAME>` in Android Studio terminal, but it doesn't kill app process.

Comment: Try with adb shell pm clear <PACKAGE_NAME>

Comment: Or check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17829677/2110064

Comment: Does your app has persistent=true in the manifest? If it doesn't, maybe your app is restarting. If you have root on your device/emulator, try killing it using kill -9 <process_id> (inside your device shell)

Comment: I use adb shell ps to show proccess in my OS. After adb shell am kill <PACKAGE NAME>, I check with adb shell ps, but my app exist in proccess list

Comment: In manifest persistent=true doesn't exist

Comment: I can't use adb shell am kill <PACKAGE NAME>, but I can use adb shell kill <PID>. But there is different both of them. I want to use adb shell am kill <PACKAGE NAME>. I will try find out what the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use `force-stop` instead

```
adb shell am force-stop package-name
```

Answer (score 0):

First use `adb shell` to see the device

Use `ps -A` to see all lists of process

you can check your app process by `ps -A | grep [package-name]`

then kill the process by `am kill [appName]` or `am force-stop [package-name]`

then check again by `ps -A | grep [package-name]` to see this process no longer exists

For example:

`ps -A | grep com.me.app`

`am kill com.me.app`

`ps -A | grep com.me.app`